# When I run my for-loop, the returned value is not the correct array value

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, nested-loops

I have tried to switch values, numbers, variables, everything, and nothing seems to work. I am still quite new to arrays so I apologize if it is a simple fix.

The nested loop is supposed to find the smallest value in the array and then return it to the main method, however, every time I just get the first number in the array.
code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7};
        int min;
        min = findMin(arr);
        System.out.println("Smallest value: " + min);
    }

    public static int findMin(int[] arr) {
        int min = arr[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < min) ;
            {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return arr[min];
    }
```

Comment: does min contain the value or the index?
do you need to return arr[min] or min ?
these 2 pointer questions should serve as guide to you as what is wrong with findMin()

Comment: min contains the value, just realized I wrote it wrong there, however when i return min I get 7. Need to return min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code,

1. remove the semicolon from the line where there's an `if` condition, with the semicolon at the end of the line if condition line is considered as a single statement

   ```
           if (arr[i] < min) 
           {
               min = arr[i];
           }
   ```
2. Also, return the `min` instead of  `arr[min]`

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this line
`if(arr[i] < min);` with `if(arr[i] < min)`

and `return arr[min];` with `return min;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should return the "min" variable; otherwise, you are asking it to find and return the "min" index in the array. If the smallest value in the array was, let's say, 100, the code would have a compile error because the array does not have 100 values in it.

`````
````        int[] arr = {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7};
````        int min;
````        min = findMin(arr);
````        System.out.println("Smallest value: " + min);
````        }

````public static int findMin(int[] arr)
````    {
````        int min = arr[0];
````        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
````        {
````            if(arr[i] < min);
````            {
````                min = arr[i];
````            }
````        }
````        return min;
````    }
`````

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should declare the length of the array using the length method at some point so you can reference it in your for loop:

```
int len = arr.length();
```

Second of all, the code should return the minimum, not the array at the index equal to the minimum number.

```
return min;
```